# Remove leading and trailing whitespaces from string in Vim

Tags: vim, neovim, removing-whitespace

I need a function which strips the leading and trailing whitespaces from a string.

```
func! RemoveWhitespaces(String)
    ...
    return formattedString
endfunc
```

I was only able to find ways to substitute lines in buffer with their whitespaces stripped but this is not what I'm looking for.

How should I complete this function?

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#substitute()

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try something and, if it breaks, ask us why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My attempt:

```
func! RemoveWhitespaces(string)
    let string = a:string
    let result = substitute(string, '\s\+$', '', '')
    let result = substitute(string, '^\s\+', '', '')
    silent return result
endfunc
```

Now to get your result you can:

```
:let var=RemoveWhitespaces('  my string with spaces   ')
:echo var
```

#### update:

As [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) commentted, there is a easier way:

```
:let var=trim('   some text   ')
```

Comment: See `:help trim()`.